# Curves that don't have lines as components

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

In my lecture notes we have the following:

A point $P=\left [x, y, z\right ]$ of an algebraic curve $C_F=V(F)$ is called an inflection point of $C_F$ when

1. $P$ is not a singular point of $C_F$.
2. The order of the tangent of $C_F$ at the point $P$ is $m_P(F)\geq 3$.

Remark: We consider the curves that don't have lines as components.

**My question is** : What does "curves that don't have lines as components" mean ???

**Edit:**

An other remark: So that the origin $P=[0, 0, 1]$ is an inflection point with the tangent at $P$ the line $$bx-ay$$

$F(x, y, z)$ will have the following form:

$$F(x, y, 1)=(bx-ay)+g_2(x, y)+g_3(x, y)+ \dots +g_d(x, y)$$ where $g_i(x, y)$ are homogeneous polynomials of degree $i$.

It should also stand that $$g_2(a \lambda , b \lambda)=\lambda^2 g_2(a, b)=0$$

Can you explain to me why it should stand that $g_2(a \lambda , b \lambda)=\lambda^2 g_2(a, b)=0$ ?

Comment: it just means that the curve doesn't contain a line.

Comment: And what does it mean that a curve contains a line @Hans ?

Comment: your curve is a subset $C$ of some affine or projective space. it means that there is no line which is a subset of $C$.

Comment: For example, the zero set of the polynomial $(y-x)(y-x^2)$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$ is the parabola $y=x^2$ union the line $y=x$. So it contains a line.

Comment: I understand! Thanks! I added at the post above also an other remark that I don't understand. Can you help me again @Hans ?

Comment: I understand! Thanks! I added at the post above also an other remark that I don't understand. Can you help me again @rfauffar ?

Answer (score 1):

Remember inflexion from Calculus. Inflexion occurs when the second derivative vanishes.

$Y=f(X)=c_1X+c_2X^2+...$ has an inflexion point at $X=0$ (the origin) if $f''(0)=0$, i.e. if $c_2=0$.

See how $c_1X,c_2X^2,...$ are homogeneous and vanish at $X=0$.

A linear change of coordinates $g$ doesn't change these conditions since $(F\circ g)''=F''\circ g\cdot (g'(z))^2$ and $g'(z)\neq0$ and homogeneous composed with linear is still homogeneous.

Now put (if $a\neq0$) $$\begin{align}X&=by-ax\\Y&=y\end{align}$$
if $a=0, b\neq0$ put $$\begin{align}X&=by\\Y&=x\end{align}$$

We never have $a=b=0$ because they are assuming the curve is not singular at the origin.